# Custom values for some of the bootstrap-sass (v2.0.3) variables not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to override some of the default variables provided by bootstrap, particularly some default color and font settings, but only a few them seem to be taking effect.  Here's the top part of my custom.css.scss:

```
$myOrange:#f89406;
$myBlueDark: #304269;
$myBlue: #91BED4;
$myBlueLight: #D9E8F5;
$myWhite: #eee;
$myGrayBlue: #43464C;

/* colors */
$linkColor: $myBlueDark;
$navbarBackground: $myBlueDark;
$navbarBackgroundHighlight: lighten($navbarBackground, 10);
$navbarLinkColor: darken($myOrange, 10);
$navbarLinkColorHover: $myOrange;
$bodyBackground: #000;
$dropdownBackground: $myBlueDark;
$dropdownLinkColor: $myOrange;
$hrBorder: $myBlue;
$heroUnitBackground: lighten($myOrange, 20);
$dropdownLinkColorHover: $myOrange;

/* typography */
$sansFontFamily: 'PT Sans Narrow', 'Lucida Grande', serif;
$baseFontSize: 16px;

@import 'bootstrap';

// ... rest of the css ....
```

Here I have specified values for a few bootstrap variables and expect the font to be be the specified one and the link colors to be the values I've set them to.

However, I've noticed that only a few of these values work.  E.g. the font on my page still stays at bootstrap default (Helvetica Neue) but the navigation bar colors change to the correct values.

I've searched around on the internet but none of the solutions I found worked.  There was an issue logged which resembles this problem, but it has since been closed: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/102

I would go ahead and comment on that thread, but I just wanted to make sure that I am not missing something.

Another thing to notice here, when I explicitly do this later in my custom.css.scss:

```
@mixin default_font {
  font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #D9E8F5;

  @include default_font;
}
```

The fonts show up fine.  I am specifying `background-color` here because of the same problem.

I am using bootstrap-sass v2.0.3. Is there something I am doing wrong or missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was working on a demo app to reproduce my problem: https://github.com/verma/bootstrap-sass-tests I restarted the rails development server.

This seems to have fixed the issue.  I am not really certain if this is a permanent fix, so I will wait before I mark this question as answered.

Comment: I've run into the same thing: being confused because my sass changes don't take effect instantly. I also will restart the rails server to force the changes to show in the browser.

Comment: Was this in development or production? If you have compiled your assets you will need to recompile and then restart the server for any stylesheet or JS file changes to take effect. In dev mode you can delete the compiled assets from /public/assets and Rails should read it from the actual stylesheets.

Comment: This was in production.  I never actually compiled any assets at all.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the **navbar-inverse** style, from the class attribute in the **header** element, may fix the problem.

Use for example:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I've had luck using this for fonts and link colors:

```
$baseFontSize:          17px;
$baseFontFamily:        'Crete Round', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !default;
$baseLineHeight:        20px;
$altFontFamily:         'Open Sans Condensed', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !default;

$headingsFontFamily:    'Alfa Slab One'; // empty to use BS default, @baseFontFamily
$headingsFontWeight:    normal;    // instead of browser default, bold
$headingsColor:         $blueDark;

$linkColor:             $blueDark;
```

The variables that you can use can be found in the [_varibles.scss file](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/f0035b8cb721d8652d4d998258f68df0613d5dbc/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss).

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I could get the fonts to change using $baseFontFamily but I still couldn't change some other variables.  It's kind of weird that some variables work while other's don't.  All of the variables I am trying to override have the !default modifier on them, so stuff should work :/ .

Answer (score 0):

What does your application.css.scss file look like?  I ran into a similar problem and found that I had another stylesheet overriding my base font, which I didn't want.  Make sure you don't have other files causing overrides (such as scaffolds.css) and make sure you do not have the require_tree option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I appended !important to the font-family for body and that fixed my issues.

Context:
I had a similar issue for my Rails 5 app where my custom fonts (.otf) was not applied. In the developer console, I see the body font applied as "Helvetica Neue" what I think is coming from bootstrap-sass.

```
body { 
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif 
...
```

when I unchecked the font-family: "Helvetica Neue", I see my fonts as expected so I know the asset pipeline for my custom fonts was working correctly.

prepending !important seemed to have fixed my issue.

```
body {
  font-family: 'Din-Light', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif' !important;
}
```